# How to add a new column to an existing dataframe while also specifying the datatype of it?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe: `yearDF` obtained from reading an RDBMS table on Postgres which I need to ingest in a Hive table on HDFS.

```
  val yearDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", connectionUrl)
                         .option("dbtable", s"(${execQuery}) as year2017")
                         .option("user", devUserName)
                         .option("password", devPassword)
                         .option("numPartitions",10)
                         .load()
```

Before ingesting it, I have to add a new column: `delete_flag` of datatype: `IntegerType` to it. This column is used to mark a primary-key whether the row is deleted in the source table or not. 
To add a new column to an existing dataframe, I know that there is the option: `dataFrame.withColumn("del_flag",someoperation)` but there is no such option to specify the datatype of new column.

I have written the StructType for the new column as:

```
val delFlagColumn = StructType(List(StructField("delete_flag", IntegerType, true)))
```

But I don't understand how to add this column with the existing dataFrame: `yearDF`. Could anyone let me know how to add a new column along with its datatype, to an existing dataFrame ?

Comment: As long as `someoperation` returns a `Column` type, I believe the data type should be inferred. If `someoperation` generates a literal `Integer`, just wrap it in a `lit()` call, to make it a `Column`.

Comment: I understand that there is lit() to generate a constant value. Just wanted to learn if there is a way to add column with datatype.

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType
df.withColumn("a", lit("1").cast(IntegerType)).show()
```

Though casting is not required if you are passing lit(1) as spark will infer the schema for you. But if you are passing as lit("1") it will cast it to Int